# Strange Postgres Hstore syntax with curly braces {key=value}

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.2, hstore

I'm using the following program https://sourceforge.net/projects/jailer/ to extract a subset of data from my database with correct associations following my foreign key constraints. The program outputs raw SQL `insert` and `update` statements than can be loaded into my development database - all very nice and handy. However - I recently started using Hstore in postgres and now I'm encountering some strange syntax in the SQL files. If I have a table witch has a column of type `store` then `update` and `insert` statements are outputted like so:

```
Update public.some_table set brand='Ford', model_name='Focus', additional_attrs={engine_size=1.6, weight=1100}, created_at=timestamp '2013-11-05 17:21:38.667085', updated_at=timestamp '2013-11-05 17:21:38.667085' Where id=246747;
```

Witch gives me the following error, when I try to execute it:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "{"
LINE 1: ...rand='Ford', model_name='Focus', additional_attrs={engine_si...
                                                             ^


********** Error **********

ERROR: syntax error at or near "{"
SQL state: 42601
Character: 81
```

As far as I know from postgresql hstore `{key=value}` is not a valid syntax so my questions are:

- Is it in fact valid syntax?
- Why would the program output syntax like this, is it likely a bug in the program or something more related to postgres e.g. the postgres jdbc driver?
- Any suggestions on how I might overcome this problem?

Comment: That syntax is plainly invalid. You should submit it as a bug to jailer developers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out it was a bug in Jailer ;-)

https://sourceforge.net/p/jailer/discussion/700499/thread/4db0ed1e/?limit=25#9eb5